# исключить строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строки с именами файлов, пропускаю эти имена через регуляру, нужно что бы регулярка не пропускала указанные расширения файлов

```
one.gif
two.png
3.jpg
four.js
5.html
six.json
seven.min.css
```

Хочу уточнить, что заведомо не известно файлы с каким расширением будут, и их количество. Сам попробовал составить

```
.*\.(?![.gif|.png|.jpg|.css])
```

Но работать не хочет.

**Обновление**

Возник еще вопрос: как отфильтровать строку у которой вдобавок есть get запрос, например, `mainLayout-min.css?d=20160427`, возможно подскажете?

Comment: IMHO endswith или строковые функции будут эффективнее.

Comment: нужна именно регулярка, другие варианты я и сам придумал бы

Comment: @user193361 квадратные скобки на круглые замените - в квадратных перечисления символов, а не строк. И точки там перед расширениями не нужны. потому как точка у вас уже проверяется перед скобками

Comment: ну так я и перечисляю последовательность символов, строки с которыми нужно убрать

Comment: `[.gif]` говорит о том, что на этом месте должен быть _один символ_, точка, или "g" или "i" или "f", но ни как не строка `.gif`. А вот с круглыми скобками нормально будет. И еще уточните какой диалект регулярных выражений у вас, может в вашем диалекте забегающих проверок (?!) нет

Comment: я буду использовать данную регулярку в консоли chrome, не знаю к сожалению какие диалекты там принимают

Comment: @user193361 Я ради интересу то что выше вам написал попробовал на regex101, по моему отлично работает `.*\.(?!(gif|png|jpg|css))` https://regex101.com/r/fZ6kD5/1

Comment: а когда есть в названии 2 точки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\.(?!(gif|png|jpg|css)$)[^.]*$
```

[тест на regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fZ6kD5/2)

**Обновление**

Для строки с get–запросом.

```
\.(?!(gif|png|jpg|css)($|\?))[^.]*($|\?)
```

Comment: работает так как надо

Answer (score 3):

```
^.*\.(gif|png|jpg|js|html|json|css)$
```

Comment: что у вас в скобках указано? зачем нужно выводить расширения?

Comment: В скобках набор расширений, которые требуются не пропускать. Если у вас произошло хоть одно совпадение, тогда файл не пропускать.

Comment: ваша регулярка не будет работать

Comment: Почему вы так думаете? Регулярное выражение говорит о том, что с начала строки могут быть любые символы, после чего точка и далее любое значение из фиксированного набора расширений, и завершается это все концом строки.

Comment: Если вам нужно только gif|png|jpg|css, то оставьте только их и все будет корректно работать, я сделал Вам маску под все файлы, которые Вы перечислили.

Comment: условие наоборот, я заведомо не знаю какие файлы будут, мне нужно исключить не нужные мне

Comment: А в чем разница то? Если Вам нужно исключить только те, которые указаны, тогда при совпадении регулярки кидайте пользователю сообщение, что его файлы не подходят, а если регулярка ничего не нашла, загружайте его на сервер и производите над ним действия.

Comment: А Если вы хотите, чтобы регулярка пропускала только эти файлы, тогда при совпадении регулярки пропускайте файлы, если ничего не нашла, то выводите сообщение.